# Binding to a userControl which contains custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls, custom-controls

I want to use the `ToggleSwitch` control of the [WPF Spark project](http://wpfspark.codeplex.com/)

So I created a `UserControl` which contains a `ToggleSwitch` control and configures it (color, size, etc).

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControls.ToggleSwitch.MyToggleSwitchControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:toggleSwitch="clr-namespace:WpfControls.ToggleSwitch"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/WpfControls;component/ToggleSwitch/ToggleSwitch.Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <toggleSwitch:ToggleSwitch x:Name="Toggle"
                                   Width="54"
                                   Height="21"
                                   Margin="0"
                                   Background="Black"
                                   BorderThickness="2"
                                   CheckedForeground="White"
                                   CheckedText="Yes"
                                   CheckedToolTip=""
                                   CornerRadius="10"
                                   FontFamily="Tahoma"
                                   FontSize="10"
                                   FontWeight="Normal"
                                   IsCheckedLeft="False"
                                   Padding="0"
                                   ThumbBorderThickness="2"
                                   ThumbCornerRadius="21"
                                   ThumbGlowColor="Gray"
                                   ThumbShineCornerRadius="20,20,0,0"
                                   ThumbWidth="35"
                                   UncheckedForeground="Black"
                                   UncheckedText="No"
                                   UncheckedToolTip="No">
        </toggleSwitch:ToggleSwitch>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The `ToggleSwitch` is a `CustomControl` which overrides the standard WPF `ToggleButton`.

Now I want to use the `ToggleButton` property `IsChecked` in my `XAML` for Binding.

```
<toggleSwitch:MyToggleSwitchControl IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create in code-behind `DependencyProperty`:

```
    public bool IsToggleChecked
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsToggleCheckedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsToggleCheckedProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsToggleCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsToggleChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(MyToggleSwitchControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

and bind it to `IsChecked` property of your `ToggleSwitch`:

```
<toggleSwitch:ToggleSwitch IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1,AncestorType=UserControl,Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=IsToggleChecked}"
```

After doing this you'll be able to do:

```
<toggleSwitch:MyToggleSwitchControl IsToggleChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
```

Comment: I get a warning that this DP hides the inherited member IsChecked of ToggleButton

Comment: I think I need to access the ToggleSwitch Control inside my UserControl somehow. Can you help me with that?

Comment: You can use 'new' key word to avoid this warning or choose other name than 'IsChecked' for this DependencyProperty.

Comment: But I think I need to set the ToggleButton.IsChecked property. Lots of styles in the CustomControl depend on that. Do I not have another property additionally then?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an dependency property.

In your custom control add a dependency property like this:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool),
        typeof(MyToggleSwitchControl), null);

    // .NET Property wrapper
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get 
        { 
            return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); 
        }
        set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean the .xaml.cs file of my usercontrol? This does not seem to work as I get a warning that this hides the IsChecked property of ToggleButton, which I want to set

Comment: Yes, I meant the .xaml.cs file, but I think, the answer from Rafal now fits your needs.